Integer solutions of $a^3+2=3b^3$
I checked this one with my computer and it seemed that there is no solution except $a=b=1$ , but I don't know if it's true or how to prove it. Here is the full question:
a, b are natural numbers. Are there any $(a, b)$ other than $(1, 1)$ such that:
$a^{3} + 2 = 3b^3$

What have you tried? For example, modulo $3$, or $9$ etc.? Compare with this post, for $7a^3+2=b^3$.

Given that there is a solution, modular techniques look less helpful.  Still,  maybe you can show that all solutions must satisfy some congruences.

It's an elliptic curve, and there are standard methods for finding integer points on such.  Non-trivial, standard methods I should stress.

I don't think my other solution was right so I deleted it, unless someone can prove whether we can assume that $\gcd\left(a^3-1,b^3-1\right)=1$. I hope this solution is correct:
Assume an integer solution $(a,b)$ exists. This means that $$a^3-1=3\left(b^3-1\right)$$Since the cubic residues $\pmod9$ are $0$, $1$ and $8$, so $a^3\equiv1\pmod9\Rightarrow 3\mid\left(a^3-1\right)$. This means that $9\mid\left(a^3-1\right)$. This occurs when $a=3c+1$, where $c\in\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore $$(3c+1)^3-1=9c\left(3c^2+3c+1\right)=3\left(b^3-1\right)$$Similarly, we must have that $3\mid\left(b^3-1\right)$, so $b^3\equiv1\pmod9$ and so $b=3d+1$ where $d\in\mathbb{Z}$. Now we have that $$9c\left(3c^2+3c+1\right)=27d\left(3d^2+3d+1\right)\Rightarrow c\left(3c^2+3c+1\right)=3d\left(3d^2+3d+1\right)$$Since $3\nmid\left(3c^2+3c+1\right)$, we must have that $c=3e$ where $c\in\mathbb{Z}$, so $$27e^2+9e+1=3d^2+3d+1\Rightarrow36e^2+12e+1=4d^2+4d+1\Rightarrow(6e+1)^2=(2d+1)^2$$Square rooting both sides gives $2d+1=\pm(6e+1)$, so $d=3e=c$ or $d=-3e-1=-c-1$.
If $c=d$ then $a=b$, which is the solution $a=b=1$.
If $d=-c-1$ then $3d=-3c-3$ so $b-1=-a-2$ and so $a^3+2=3\left(-a-3\right)^3$ which clearly does not have any integer solutions.
Therefore the only solution is $a=b=1$.
